# Removing multiple keys from a dictionary safely

Tags: python, dictionary

I know how to remove an entry, `'key'` from my dictionary `d`, safely. You do:

```
if d.has_key('key'):
    del d['key']
```

However, I need to remove multiple entries from a dictionary safely.  I was thinking of defining the entries in a tuple as I will need to do this more than once.

```
entities_to_remove = ('a', 'b', 'c')
for x in entities_to_remove:
    if x in d:
        del d[x]
```

However, I was wondering if there is a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Retrieval time from a dictionary is nearly O(1) because of hashing.  Unless you are removing a significant proportion of the entries, I don't think you will do much better.

Comment: The answer of @mattbornski seems more canonical, and also succincter.

Comment: StackOverflow hath spoken: `key in d` is more Pythonic than `d.has_key(key)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323410/has-key-or-in

Comment: If you can spare a bit of memory, you can do `for x in set(d) & entities_to_remove: del d[x]`.  This will probably only be more efficient if `entities_to_remove` is "large".

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Why not like this:

```
entries = ('a', 'b', 'c')
the_dict = {'b': 'foo'}

def entries_to_remove(entries, the_dict):
    for key in entries:
        if key in the_dict:
            del the_dict[key]
```

A more compact version was provided by mattbornski using [dict.pop()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995774/948369)

Comment: Adding this for people coming from a search engine. If keys are known (when safety is not an issue), multiple keys can be deleted in one line like this `del dict['key1'], dict['key2'], dict['key3']`

Comment: Depending on the number of keys you're deleting, it might be more efficient to use `for key in set(the_dict) & entries:` and bypass the `key in dict` test.

Answer (score 362):

Using [`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop):

```
d = {'some': 'data'}
entries_to_remove = ('any', 'iterable')
for k in entries_to_remove:
    d.pop(k, None)
```

Comment: **This.** This is the clever Pythonista's choice. `dict.pop()` eliminates the need for key existence testing. _Excellent._

Comment: For what it's worth, I think `.pop()` is bad and unpythonic, and would prefer the accepted answer over this one.

Comment: A staggering number of people appear unbothered by this :)

I don't mind the extra line for existence checking personally, and it's significantly more readable unless you already know about pop().  On the other hand if you were trying to do this in a comprehension or inline lambda this trick could be a big help.

I'd also say that it's important, in my opinion, to meet people where they are.  I'm not sure that "bad and unpythonic" is going to give the people who are reading these answers the practical guidance they are looking for.

Comment: There is a particularly *good* reason to use this. While adding an extra line may improve "readability" or "clarity", it also adds an extra lookup to the dictionary. This method is the removal equivalent of doing `setdefault`. If implemented correctly (and I'm sure it is), it only does one lookup into the hash-map that is the `dict`, instead of two.

Comment: I'm not very sure, but `k in d` + `del d[k]` may still be faster than `d.pop(k)` because `pop` may involve a function call, while `in` and `del` somehow may not. BTW, in my experience, `k in d` + `d[k]` in CPython is usually faster than `d.get(k)`. There are some articles/questions talking about this.

Comment: Personally I would be concerned with correctness and maintainability first, and speed only if it is proven to be insufficiently fast.  The speed difference between these operations is going to be trivial when zoomed out to the application level.  It may be the case that one is faster, but I expect that in real world usage you will neither notice nor care, and if you do notice and care, you will be better served rewriting in something more performant than Python.

Comment: This is not "bad and unpythonic". `pop` is very common and very pythonic. Alternately, you could just try/except, but that's what is already built into pop. Carry on.

Comment: Reminder - if you're testing this and using just one key, you need to do like:  entriesToRemove('any',).   (with that extra ',' at the end).  If you forget the comma, it will instead test with each letter.

Answer (score 128):

Using **Dict Comprehensions**

```py
final_dict = {key: value for key, value in d.items() if key not in [key1, key2]}
```

where **key1** and **key2** are to be removed.

In the example below, keys "b" and "c" are to be removed & it's kept in a keys list.

```
>>> a
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
>>> keys = ["b", "c"]
>>> print {key: a[key] for key in a if key not in keys}
{'a': 1, 'd': 4}
>>>
```

Comment: new dictionary? list comprehension? You should adjust the answer to the person asking the question ;)

Comment: it creates a new dictionary but it was a one liner, so I mentioned it.

Comment: This solution has a serious performance hit when the variable holding the has further use in the program. In other words, a dict from which keys have been deleted is much more efficient than a newly created dict with the retained items.

Comment: @shadyabhi. beautiful, very pythonic ! One often forget that optimization and side effect are evil....

Comment: for the sake of readability, I suggest  {k:v  for k,v in t.items() if k not in [key1, key2]}

Comment: This also has performance issues when the list of keys is too big, as searches take `O(n)`. The whole operation is `O(mn)`, where `m` is the number of keys in the dict and `n` the number of keys in the list. I suggest using a set `{key1, key2}` instead, if possible.

Comment: To Apalala: can you help me understand why there's an performance hit?

Comment: @Sean The program needs to allocate memory for a second dictionary, iterate through every key on the first dictionary and do a full-value compare (as opposed to a hash compare), check if its in the 'keys' list by iterating through that list every pass of the comprehension, then copy to the second dictionary if not. 

By deleting, all that is happening is the first dictionary looks up the key's hash value and removes it. Then the garbage collector takes care of the rest. Therefore this is much faster.

Comment: Removal is better than reconstruction of an entire dict. Complexity is of also order of N. Not really pythonic way of doing

Comment: There's and error in the first example.  It needs to read: ``for key, value in d.items()``.

Answer (score 23):

a solution is using `map` and `filter` functions

**python 2**

```
d={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
l=("a","b","d")
map(d.__delitem__, filter(d.__contains__,l))
print(d)
```

**python 3**

```
d={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
l=("a","b","d")
list(map(d.__delitem__, filter(d.__contains__,l)))
print(d)
```

you get:

```
{'c': 3}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me with python 3.4: `>>> d={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
>>> l=("a","b","d")
>>> map(d.__delitem__, filter(d.__contains__,l))
<map object at 0x10579b9e8>
>>> print(d)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`

Comment: @Risadinha `list(map(d.__delitem__,filter(d.__contains__,l)))` .... in python 3.4 map function return a iterator

Comment: or `deque(map(...), maxlen=0)` to avoid building a list of None values; first import with `from collections import deque`

Answer (score 21):

If you also need to retrieve the values for the keys you are removing, this would be a pretty good way to do it:

```
values_removed = [d.pop(k, None) for k in entities_to_remove]
```

You could of course still do this just for the removal of the keys from `d`, but you would be unnecessarily creating the list of values with the list comprehension.  It is also a little unclear to use a list comprehension just for the function's side effect.

Comment: Or if you wanted to keep the deleted entries *as a dictionary:* `valuesRemoved = dict((k, d.pop(k, None)) for k in entitiesToRemove)` and so on.

Comment: You can leave away the assignment to a variable. In this or that way it's the shortest and most pythonic solution and should be marked as the corect answer IMHO.

Answer (score 18):

Found a solution with `pop` and `map`

```
d = {'a': 'valueA', 'b': 'valueB', 'c': 'valueC', 'd': 'valueD'}
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list(map(d.pop, keys))
print(d)
```

The output of this:

```
{'d': 'valueD'}
```

I have answered this question so late just because I think it will help in the future if anyone searches the same. And this might help.

**Update**

The above code will throw an error if a key does not exist in the dict.

```
DICTIONARY = {'a': 'valueA', 'b': 'valueB', 'c': 'valueC', 'd': 'valueD'}
keys = ['a', 'l', 'c']

def remove_key(key):
    DICTIONARY.pop(key, None)
    

list(map(remove_key, keys))
print(DICTIONARY)
```

output:

```
DICTIONARY = {'b': 'valueB', 'd': 'valueD'}
```

Comment: This answer will throw an exception if any key in `keys` does not exist in `d` - you would have to filter that first.

Comment: @ingofreyer updated the code for exception handling. Thanks for finding this issue. I think now it will work. :)

Comment: Thanks, this should help everyone finding this answer :-)

Comment: Creating a list as a by-product of using map, makes this quite slow, it's actually better to loop over it.

Answer (score 18):

Some timing tests for cpython 3 shows that a simple for loop is the fastest way, and it's quite readable.   Adding in a function doesn't cause much overhead either:

timeit results (10k iterations):

- `all(x.pop(v) for v in r)    # 0.85`
- `all(map(x.pop, r))          # 0.60`
- `list(map(x.pop, r))         # 0.70`
- `all(map(x.__delitem__, r))  # 0.44`
- `del_all(x, r)               # 0.40`
- `<inline for loop>(x, r)     # 0.35`

```
def del_all(mapping, to_remove):
      """Remove list of elements from mapping."""
      for key in to_remove:
          del mapping[key]
```

For small iterations, doing that 'inline' was a bit faster, because of the overhead of the function call.   But `del_all` is lint-safe, reusable, and faster than all the python comprehension and mapping constructs.

Comment: Good function. Just make sure to handle the exception if a key was not found.

Answer (score 8):

I have tested the performance of three methods:

```py
# Method 1: `del`
for key in remove_keys:
    if key in d:
        del d[key]

# Method 2: `pop()`
for key in remove_keys:
    d.pop(key, None)

# Method 3: comprehension
{key: v for key, v in d.items() if key not in remove_keys}
```

Here are the results of 1M iterations:

1. `del`: 2.03s 2.0 ns/iter (100%)
2. `pop()`: 2.38s 2.4 ns/iter (117%)
3. comprehension: 4.11s 4.1 ns/iter (202%)

So both `del` and `pop()` are the fastest. Comprehensions are 2x slower.
But anyway, we speak *nanoseconds* here :) Dicts in Python are ridiculously fast.

Comment: You forgot an `t` in the `no` word

Answer (score 7):

I have no problem with any of the existing answers, but I was surprised to not find this solution:

```
keys_to_remove = ['a', 'b', 'c']
my_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip("a b c d e f g".split(' '), [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])}

for k in keys_to_remove:
    try:
        del my_dict[k]
    except KeyError:
        pass

assert my_dict == {'d': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6}
```

Note: I stumbled across this question coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30350598/1843248). And my answer is related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995774/1843248).

Comment: Checking for membership is easier (and faster) than running try: except:

Answer (score 3):

Why not:

```
entriestoremove = (2,5,1)
for e in entriestoremove:
    if d.has_key(e):
        del d[e]
```

I don't know what you mean by "smarter way". Surely there are other ways, maybe with dictionary comprehensions:

```
entriestoremove = (2,5,1)
newdict = {x for x in d if x not in entriestoremove}
```

Answer (score 1):

**inline**

```
import functools

#: not key(c) in d
d = {"a": "avalue", "b": "bvalue", "d": "dvalue"}

entitiesToREmove = ('a', 'b', 'c')

#: python2
map(lambda x: functools.partial(d.pop, x, None)(), entitiesToREmove)

#: python3

list(map(lambda x: functools.partial(d.pop, x, None)(), entitiesToREmove))

print(d)
# output: {'d': 'dvalue'}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to have full support for set methods for dictionaries (and not the unholy mess we're getting with Python 3.9) so that you could simply "remove" a set of keys. However, as long as that's not the case, and you have a large dictionary with potentially a large number of keys to remove, you might want to know about the performance. So, I've created some code that creates something large enough for meaningful comparisons: a 100,000 x 1000 matrix, so 10,000,00 items in total.

```
from itertools import product
from time import perf_counter

# make a complete worksheet 100000 * 1000
start = perf_counter()
prod = product(range(1, 100000), range(1, 1000))
cells = {(x,y):x for x,y in prod}
print(len(cells))

print(f"Create time {perf_counter()-start:.2f}s")
clock = perf_counter()
# remove everything above row 50,000

keys = product(range(50000, 100000), range(1, 100))

# for x,y in keys:
#     del cells[x, y]

for n in map(cells.pop, keys):
    pass

print(len(cells))
stop = perf_counter()
print(f"Removal time {stop-clock:.2f}s")
```

10 million items or more is not unusual in some settings. Comparing the two methods on my local machine I see a slight improvement when using `map` and `pop`, presumably because of fewer function calls, but both take around 2.5s on my machine. But this pales in comparison to the time required to create the dictionary in the first place (55s), or including checks within the loop. If this is likely then its best to create a set that is a intersection of the dictionary keys and your filter:

`keys = cells.keys() & keys`

In summary: `del` is already heavily optimised, so don't worry about using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the fact that the keys can be treated as a set is the nicest way if you're on python 3:

```
def remove_keys(d, keys):
    to_remove = set(keys)
    filtered_keys = d.keys() - to_remove
    filtered_values = map(d.get, filtered_keys)
    return dict(zip(filtered_keys, filtered_values))
```

Example:

```
>>> remove_keys({'k1': 1, 'k3': 3}, ['k1', 'k2'])
{'k3': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another map() way to remove list of keys from dictionary**

and avoid raising KeyError exception

```
    dic = {
        'key1': 1,
        'key2': 2,
        'key3': 3,
        'key4': 4,
        'key5': 5,
    }
    
keys_to_remove = ['key_not_exist', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3']
k = list(map(dic.pop, keys_to_remove, keys_to_remove))

print('k=', k)
print('dic after =  \n', dic)

**this will produce output** 

k= ['key_not_exist', 1, 2, 3]
dic after =  {'key4': 4, 'key5': 5}
```

Duplicate `keys_to_remove` is artificial, it needs to supply defaults values for dict.pop() function.
You can add here any array with len_ = len(key_to_remove)

---

For example

```
dic = {
    'key1': 1,
    'key2': 2,
    'key3': 3,
    'key4': 4,
    'key5': 5,
}

keys_to_remove = ['key_not_exist', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3']    
k = list(map(dic.pop, keys_to_remove, np.zeros(len(keys_to_remove))))

print('k=', k)
print('dic after = ', dic)
```

** will produce output **

```
k= [0.0, 1, 2, 3]
dic after =  {'key4': 4, 'key5': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def delete_keys_from_dict(dictionary, keys):
"""
Deletes the unwanted keys in the dictionary
:param dictionary: dict
:param keys: list of keys
:return: dict (modified)
"""
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

keys_set = set(keys)
modified_dict = {}
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if key not in keys_set:
        if isinstance(value, list):
            modified_dict[key] = list()
            for x in value:
                if isinstance(x, MutableMapping):
                    modified_dict[key].append(delete_keys_from_dict(x, keys_set))
                else:
                    modified_dict[key].append(x)
        elif isinstance(value, MutableMapping):
            modified_dict[key] = delete_keys_from_dict(value, keys_set)
        else:
            modified_dict[key] = value
return modified_dict


_d = {'a': 1245, 'b': 1234325, 'c': {'a': 1245, 'b': 1234325}, 'd': 98765,
      'e': [{'a': 1245, 'b': 1234325},
            {'a': 1245, 'b': 1234325},
            {'t': 767}]}

_output = delete_keys_from_dict(_d, ['a', 'b'])
_expected = {'c': {}, 'd': 98765, 'e': [{}, {}, {'t': 767}]}
print(_expected)
print(_output)
```

Answer (score -4):

I'm late to this discussion but for anyone else. A solution may be to create a list of keys as such.

```
k = ['a','b','c','d']
```

Then use pop() in a list comprehension, or for loop, to iterate over the keys and pop one at a time as such.

```
new_dictionary = [dictionary.pop(x, 'n/a') for x in k]
```

The 'n/a' is in case the key does not exist, a default value needs to be returned.

Comment: `new_dictionary` looks an awful lot like a list ;)