# Keep some keys in my list with comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a big list that I pulled in from a .csv:

```
CSV_PATH = 'myfile.csv'
CSV_OBJ = csv.DictReader(open(CSV_PATH, 'r'))
CSV_LIST = list(CSV_OBJ)
```

And I only want to keep some of the columns in it:

```
KEEP_COLS = ['Name', 'Year', 'Total Allocations', 'Enrollment']'
```

It seems from [Removing multiple keys from a dictionary safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995611/removing-multiple-keys-from-a-dictionary-safely) like this ought to work:

```
BETTER = {k: v for k, v in CSV_LIST if k not in KEEP_COLS}
```

But I get an error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack` What am I missing here? I could write a loop that runs through CSV_LIST and produces BETTER by keeping only what I want, but I suspect that using comprehension is more pythonic.

As requested, a chunk of CSV_LIST

```
{'EIN': '77-0000091',
  'FR': '28.4',
  'Name': 'Org A',
  'Enrollment': '506',
  'Total Allocations': '$34214',
  'geo_latitude': '37.9381775755',
  'geo_longitude': '-122.3146910612',
  'Year': '2009'},
 {'EIN': '77-0000091',
  'FR': '28.4',
  'Name': 'Org A',
  'Enrollment': '506',
  'Total Allocations': '$34214',
  'geo_latitude': '37.9381775755',
  'geo_longitude': '-122.3146910612',
  'Year': '2010'}
```

At the commandline I can do  `csvcut -c 'Name','Year','Total Allocations','Enrollment' myfile.csv > better_myfile.csv` but that's definitely not pythonic.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that all the items of `CSV_LIST` aren't a two item list/tuple. Could you print a bit of `CSV_LIST` and post the output here?

Comment: I wound up using csvcut http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/csvcut.html#examples to get what I need, but it isn't a perfect solution.

Comment: @Amanda: tip for the future-- while it's useful to add the version tags, you should also add the general `python` tag.  You'll note that after I edited the tags there were answers posted within a few minutes; not everyone subscribes to the version-specific tags.  [Some of that's just time zone effects, but I've seen this happen many times before.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary comprehension is fine, but since you have a *list* of dictionaries, you have to create a list comprehension using that dictionary comprehension for the individual list items. Also, since you want to *keep* those columns, I guess you should drop that `not`. Try this:

```
[{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in KEEP_COLS} for d in CSV_LIST]
```

Comment: Boom. Thank you. I woulda noticed the "NOT" issue eventually. The list of dicts, not so much.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use

```
CSV_LIST = map(operator.itemgetter(*KEEP_LIST), CSV_OBJ)
```

This will create a list of tuples with the desired columns.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `CSV_LIST` is a **list**, not a single `dict`. [@tobias explained how to unpack it correctly.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22175955/2069350)

---

However, if you're worried about being Pythonic, why are you processing a `DictReader` into a list of dictionaries and then filtering out all but a few keys? Without knowing your use case I can't be sure, but it's likely that it would be cleaner and simpler to just use the `DictReader` row-by-row the way it was intended to be used:

```
with open(CSV_PATH, 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        process(row['Name'],row['Year'],row['Total Allocations'],row['Enrollment'])
```

Comment: Makes sense, though this seems like it should also work: `CSV_OBJ = csv.DictReader(open(CSV_PATH, 'r'), KEEP_COLS)` -- and it does get close.