# Deleting dictionary keys from a provided list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I was trying to delete some dictionary items from a provided black_list and I would like to know (since I am new to this language) if there is a better alternative to the code I've implemented:

```
for unwanted_item in black_list:
            for item_name in dict.keys():
                    if unwanted_item in item_name:
                            del dict[item_name]
```

Thanks :)

Comment: In python 2 this looks fine.  It will break in python 3 though.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting