# Remove keys from object not in a list in python?

Tags: python

I have these keys:

```
keep = ["a","c"]
```

My dict:

```
testdict = {'
'a':'vala',
'b':'valb',
'c':'valc',
'd':'vald'
}
```

Desired output:

```
testdict = {
'a':'vala',
'c':'valc'
}
```

I want to remove all keys that do not match the key in the list.
What is the fastest way to do this?

I tried:

```
for key, value in testdict.iteritems():
      if key not in keep:
         del testdict[key]
```

But the above gives me errors since the size is changing.

Comment: How big can `keep` become?

Comment: keep may just have 4 or 5 keys

Comment: what if keep contains a key not in testDict?

Comment: this could help you [removing-multiple-keys-from-a-dictionary-safely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995611/removing-multiple-keys-from-a-dictionary-safely/)

Answer (score 35):

Instead of removing, simply construct a new dict:

```
newdict = {k: testdict[k] for k in keep}
```

If `keep` can contain keys that are not present in testdict, add the appropriate condition:

```
newdict = {k: testdict[k] for k in keep if k in testdict}
```

If you absolutely must modify the dict object, bear in mind that you can not modify a dictionary while you're traversing over it. So traverse first and delete afterwards:

```
to_delete = set(testdict.keys()).difference(keep)
for d in to_delete:
    del testdict[d]
```

Comment: You get a KeyError if k is not in testdict. Would `newdict = {k: testdict[k] for k in keep if k in testdict}` not be better?

Comment: or possibly `{k: testdict.get(k, None) for k in keep}`

Comment: @msw In general, I'd *want* an exception if keep is invalid, instead of later finding "invalid" dicts and guessing where they came from. But this depends on the specific use case. I've amended the answer.

Comment: @phihag I agree, there is not quite enough information in the OP to choose between the two. Elegant answer, regardless.

Comment: no need to constuct a new dict: `testdict = {k: testdict[k] for k in keep if k in testdict}`, regardless a nice answer above!

Answer (score 3):

```
print({k:testDict[k] for k in keep})
```

or in py<2.7

```
print dict((k,testDict[k]) for k in keep)
```

these assume every key in keep is guaranteed to exist in `testDict`

Comment: Dict comprehensions are available in Python 2.7! In any case, why are you constructing a list just to feed into dict instead of using a generator expression?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're mutating the keys while using the iterator. If you had a proper list of the keys you could avoid the issue..

```
for key in list(testdict.keys()):
      if key not in keep:
         del testdict[key]
```