# Python functional approach: remove key from dict using filter

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

A follow up on the recent question [Remove keys from object not in a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727294/remove-keys-from-object-not-in-a-list-in-python)

That question turns out to be a duplicate of a previous one. All answers there, and among them the most voted, use list comprehension. I'm thinking on a functional approach. How can this be done using `filter`?

We have:

```
testdict={'a':'vala', 'b':'valb', 'c':'valc','d':'vald'}
keep=['a','c']
```

and I want

```
filter(isKept,testdict)
```

to give

```
{'a':'vala','c':'valc'}
```

I tried naively defining `isKept` as a function of either one (the keys) or two variables (keys, values) but the former just filters out the right keys *without* the corresponding values (i.e., a list, not a dictionary). The latter way doesn't even parse correctly.

Is there a filter for dictionaries in Python?

Notice that `testdict.pop(k)` is not what I want as this deletes, but the question here is *to keep*.

Comment: `filter` is not a good way to accomplish such thing as it always returns a list including filtered values so it doesn't make sense modifying the original list with that.

Comment: @ozgur Yes, I kinda noticed that filter doesn't seem to apply to dictionaries, but rather lists. Hence my last question, is there a filter function for dicts that can be used *à la functional*?

Comment: Yes, but you should convert dictionary to a list first using `dict.items()`

Comment: I think you're somewhat confused on what `functional` in functional programming generally means.

Comment: What is wrong with the dict comprehension?

Comment: @wim nothing wrong per se. And Falmarri , yes, I admit some biased knowledge of it, or simple confusion. I'm sorry that I gave the impression I don't value the answer as list comprehension. One user just deleted his answer and I think now it is pertinent as both of you adequately point out. I was writing to him "PD: I haven't seen many case examples, but the python (or scala) code I usually see used in Spark tends to end up in a composition of maps and filters. That's what (mis)lead my wording in the question." when (s)he deleted the answer. Any way, hope this helps clarify my question.

Comment: That said, I would like to understand more in which way list comprehension *is* a functional approach. I've seen that before in Haskell, but I always saw it as an (often ugly) recourse of the language. I kept the more naive idea of functions without side-effects and composition of functions as a working definition of *functional* in functional programming. Any pointer to further illustrate this would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ozgur Thanks! I see that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Truth be told using comprehensions is as functional as it gets, but if that's not what you want [`toolz`](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz) library provides a nice set of functions including `keyfilter`:

```
>>> from toolz.dicttoolz import keyfilter
>>> to_keep = lambda key: key in set(keep)
>>> keyfilter(to_keep, testdict)
{'a': 'vala', 'c': 'valc'}
```

Comment: Aha! Didn't know about toolz. Yes, that is exactly what I had in mind. I was thinking on this *compositional* approach because it seems to me more readable when further composing with other functions (say additional maps and filters).

Comment: I got to give that a closer look. Thanks again for that additional pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Functions like `filter()`, `map()` and `reduce()` do not modify the original sequence you pass to them. They return a new sequence or value. In addition to that, if you want to use `filter()` on dicts, you should convert it to list first using `.items()` or better yet, to an iterator via `.iteritems()`:

```
>>> testdict = {'a':'vala', 'b':'valb', 'c':'valc','d':'vald'}
>>> keep = ['a','c']
>>> print dict(filter(lambda entry: entry[0] in keep, testdict.items()))
{'a': 'vala', 'c': 'valc'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems way closer to what I had in mind, albeit python is kind of cheating here as first we need to translate the dict into a list of tuples. Does it mean there really is no "natural" filter function for dicts and we need to hack our own -e.g., as you show us here?

Comment: No, because in functional programming languages like scheme, lisp etc., these functions are applied to a series of values and produce another set of values. They don't modify the given input sequence in-place.

Comment: Not sure I follow you here. I'd say map(function,list) in python behaves just like that, i.e., it doesn't modify list. Your own answer doesn't modify testdict either. So, it seems we do have "strict functions" in python.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood it. Your question's answer is No. There is no builtin  filter function which operates on dicts. This is why there is a 3rd party function named `toolz.keyfilter` which basically operates on just keys.

Comment: Thanks again! I think that completes the answer to my original question. I don't think I can accept two or more answers, and it seems only fair to do so for zero323 as it explicitly constructs the solution I asked for. Hope you don't see this as disregarding your contribution. It isn't!

Answer (score 2):

A dict comprehension is as functional as it gets (i.e. it is both declarative and stateless):

```
{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in keep}
```

Furthermore, it is pythonic (i.e. it is explicit, readable, and succinct). You really should prefer this style.

Answer (score 0):

```
testdict={'a':'vala', 'b':'valb', 'c':'valc','d':'vald'}
keep=['a','c']

def isKept(dict_item):
  if dict_item[0] in keep:
    return True
  else:
    return False

print(dict(filter(isKept,testdict.items())))
```

Comment: In `isKept`, why not just `return dict_item[0] in kept`?