# pythonic way to delete edge attributes

Tags: networkx

In order to remove attributes from a networkx graph I have the following code:

```
for (n1,n2) in graph.edges(data=False):  
    for att in att_list:  
        graph[n1][n2].pop(att, None)
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to delete a few attributes in some list, say `att_list`

```
for n1, n2, d in graph.edges(data=True):
    for att in att_list:
        d.pop(att, None)
```

Or you can replace the last line with `if att in d: del d[att]` if it bothers you that `pop` returns something that you aren't using.  The improvement compared to your code is that by having `data=True` I get `d` immediately, rather than having to reference `graph[n1][n1]` later.

See [Removing multiple keys from a dictionary safely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8995611/2966723) for how to remove multiple keys from a dictionary (which is what `d` is).  Fundamentally that's what your problem reduces to once you've got `d`.

Alternately, if you want to clear all of the attributes, then note that if we set `data=True`, then `graph.edges` also returns a dictionary with the attributes.  Clear this dictionary.

```
for (n1, n2, d) in graph.edges(data=True):
    d.clear()
```

Here's a complete example

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=2)
G.edge[1][2]
> {'weight': 5}

for (n1, n2, d) in G.edges(data=True):
    d.clear()
G.edge[1][2]
> {}
#just to check the edge in the opposite order
G.edge[2][1]
> {}
```

Comment: In our case we need to delete only part of the attributes - not all of them.