# Python 3.x - dataframe comprehension based on subset of defaultdict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have myself a default dict like so:

```
dict_items([('62007459', 0), ('68092193', 0), ('40224646', 120.92999999999999), ('68078141', 0), ('68061506', 0), ('60000216', 123.84), ...])
```

However, I will not need all of the entries. Instead, I want to use a subset of these. I have the desired keys stored as a simple native python `list`, a list of strings:

```
lcodes = ['40224646','60000216', ... ]
```

The following gives me a nice dataframe for the whole bit:
(z_lookup is just a dict that matches two kinds of ids)

```
df_all = pd.DataFrame([(k, z_lookup.get(k, 'N/A'), v) for k, v in 
                          output.items()], columns=['id','zcode','values'])
```

I can access values one at a time, for instance: `output['62007459']` gives me `0`, which is correct. But I'm not sure how to scale up/iterate this process so that the pandas dataframe is only created from the keys in `output` that are present in `lcodes`.

### Question

Given a defaultdict and a native python list of keys to filter by/keep, how do I use this information to tell pandas I want a dataframe from only entries in the defaultdict that are represented in a separate list of string containing keys to keep?

Comment: `df_all = pd.DataFrame([(k, z_lookup.get(k, 'N/A'), v) for k, v in output.items() if k in lcodes], columns=['id','zcode','values'])` perhaps?

Comment: Or maybe `df_all = pd.DataFrame([(k, z_lookup.get(k, 'N/A'), output.get(k)) for k in set(output) & set(lcodes)], columns=['id','zcode','values'])`

Answer (score 1):

If it is OK to remove the unwanted data, the easiest solution might be to just [filter out items from your default dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995611/removing-multiple-keys-from-a-dictionary-safely) before using it to initialise the dataframe.

After you filter out the unwanted data, you can just create the dataframe as you are doing it now; example:

```
# filter unwanted keys, assuming 'output' is your default dict
for lcode in lcodes:
    output.pop(lcode, None)

# create dataframe from only desired data
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, z_lookup.get(k, 'N/A'), v) for k, v in 
                          output.items()], columns=['id','zcode','values'])
```

While it adds two extra lines of code for filtering, imho doing it in two steps is slightly more readable.