# Efficiency difference between dict.has_key and key in dict in Python

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['has_key()' or 'in'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323410/has-key-or-in)

In Python, there're two ways of deciding whether a `key` is in a `dict`:

`if dict.has_key(key)` and `if key in dict`

Someone tells me that the second one is slower than the first one since the `in` keyword makes the expression an iteration over the dict, so it will be slower than the `has_key` alternative, which apparently uses hash to make the decision.

As I highly doubt the difference, since I think Python is smart enough to translate an `in` keyword before a `dict` to some hash way, I can't find any formal claim about this.

So is there really any efficiency difference between the two?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Both of these operations do the same thing: examine the hash table implemented in the dict for the key.  Neither will iterate the entire dictionary.  Keep in mind that `for x in dict` is different than `if x in dict`.  They both use the `in` keyword, but are different operations.

The `in` keyword becomes a call on `dict.__contains__`, which dict can implement however it likes.

If there is a difference in the timings of these operations, it will be very small, and will have to do with the function call overhead of `has_key`.

BTW, the general preference is for `key in dict` as a clearer expression of the intent than `dict.has_key(key)`.  Note that speed has nothing to do with the preference.  Readability is more important than speed unless you know you are in the critical path.

Comment: ....all of this, and in addition, 'has_key()' is deprecated and should no longer be used. :)

Answer (score 3):

`D.has_key` is actually slower due to the function call:

```
>>> D = dict((x, y) for x, y in zip(range(1000000), range(1000000)))
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> t = Timer("1700 in D", "from __main__ import D")
>>> t.timeit()
0.10631704330444336
>>> t = Timer("D.has_key(1700)", "from __main__ import D")
>>> t.timeit()
0.18113207817077637
```

Comment: Well considering that timeit runs the statement a million times, and the number is is in seconds, the *absolute* time difference is pretty small

Comment: Something like 80 nanoseconds..

Comment: It's nearly a factor of two difference, though. You make a good point (implicitly) about focusing optimization efforts in meaningful places, but still.

Answer (score 3):

`has_key` isn't an alternative. It's deprecated. Don't use it. (It's slower anyhow)