# 'HostKeys' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Tags: python, paramiko

I m the way to upload files over sftp using paramiko but i am getting this error.

> ri@ri-desktop:~/workspace/ssh$ python testssh.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "testssh.py", line 75, in 
>       if host_keys.has_key(hostname):
>   AttributeError: 'HostKeys' object has no attribute 'has_key'

This is the code inside my test.py

```
hostkeytype = None
hostkey = None
files_copied = 0

try:
    host_keys = paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))<br/>

except IOError: 
    try:
        # try ~/ssh/ too, e.g. on windows
        host_keys = paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/ssh/known_hosts'))
    except IOError:
        print '*** Unable to open host keys file'
        host_keys = {}
if host_keys.has_key(hostname):
    hostkeytype = host_keys[hostname].keys()[0]

    hostkey = host_keys[hostname][hostkeytype]
    print 'Using host key of type {0}'.format(hostkeytype)
```

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар, the  '*** Unable to open host keys file' would be printed if that was the case.

Comment: where is hostname coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/ssh/known_hosts'))
```

Either one of these functions runs successfully and returns an object that doesn't have a `has_key` attribute, or you're using python 3, where `has_key` [has been removed from dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323410/has-key-or-in).

Since you are using python 2.x, the problem should be that these functions return something that is doesn't have `has_key` attribute

I had a look at the source code for [paramiko.util](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/util.py) and indeed, `util.load_host_keys` returns something else than a dict, namely a [HostKeys object](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/paramiko/hostkeys.py) which does not implement `has_key()`, so you cannot call that function on your `host_keys` object

Because the docstring for HostKeys class says this

> A `.HostKeys` object can be treated like a dict; any dict lookup is
>       equivalent to calling `lookup`.

you could use this instead

```
if hostname in host_keys:
```

Answer (score 0):

just test if host_keys is a dictionary by adding this piece of code:`print type(host_keys)`

before  `if host_keys.has_key(hostname):`

Answer (score 0):

What version of Python do you use ? Because `has_key` has been deprecated in 3.xx :

> Removed. dict.has_key() – use the in operator instead.

Source : https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html