# how come key in dictionary.keys() slower than key in dictionary?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, dictionary

While reading *Python 101* by *Michael Driscoll* I got to his explanation on checking if a key exists in a dictionary. I checked it on my machine with a dictionary containing keys `'a'` to `'z'` where the value is their order, and a function that measures time on retrieving the key `'t'` (picked it at random)

Here's my function:

```
def f(d, flag):
start_time = time.time()
if flag:
    print("t" in d)
else:
    print("t" in d.keys())
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

And here are the results:

```
>>> f(dict,True)
True
--- 0.03937530517578125 seconds ---

>>> f(dict,False)
True
--- 0.05114388465881348 seconds ---
```

BUT, I still don't get it. I thought that `key in dict.keys()` would result in iteration on much smaller collection, which will be faster. Is there something special in the implementation of `in` or `keys()` that causes this?

Comment: Because you need to create an additional object first.

Comment: But why downvoted?

Comment: Why did you think that `dict.keys()` would test against a smaller collection? What would that collection not include that `key in dict` would?

Comment: I thought that dict is a collection of pairs and I will search each pair instead of searching a list of one-item-object, and that accessing the pair would also cost CPU time. Moreover I thought that returning keys would be a small and fast operation

Comment: Note that if you were using Python 2, the timings would be much more different https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540975/why-does-key-in-d-keys-finish-in-on-time-while-key-in-d-finishes-in-o1 and could be a dupe of this (see the Python 3 relevant part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539367/python-dictionary-keys-in-complexity)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `dictionary.keys()` is slower because it does *more work*:

- It adds an attribute lookup; `dictionary.keys`
- It adds a method call (`keys()`), requiring the current call frame to be pushed onto the stack, and popped afterwards.
- Another object has to be created for the return value (a dictionary view). It's a light-weight object, but you still need to allocate memory for it on the heap.

None of this is needed, because a containment test against the dictionary and the dictionary view on the keys test *the exact same thing*. Containment testing directly on a dictionary does not include the values, you are testing for keys *only*, in both cases.

From the [`dict()` object documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> `key in d`
>   Return `True` if *d* has a key *key*, else `False`.

Note that using walk-clock time is not a great way of testing for performance differences. Use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) instead, which picks the best performing timer, disables the GC to eliminate a source of skew, and repeats the test many times to minimise system skew.

You can reproduce the time difference by testing for the additional steps above separately (combining the call and object creation into one). By default `timeit.timet()` repeats the test 1 million times and returns the total time taken:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> d = {l: i for i, l in enumerate(ascii_lowercase)}
>>> 't' in d
True
>>> timeit.timeit('d.keys', globals={'d': d})
0.0439452639548108
>>> timeit.timeit('keys()', globals={'keys': d.keys})
0.06267352704890072
```

So merely looking up the `.keys` attribute 1 million times already takes 44 milliseconds, while calling the method (without attribute lookup) adds another 63ms. Both methods have some overhead for looking up the global name however:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('d', globals={'d': d})
0.027833244064822793
```

So one would expect there to be a 107 - 28 == 79ms (roughly) difference between the two methods.

And indeed, the time difference between using `'t' in d` and `'t' in d.keys()` is about that much:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('"t" in d.keys()', globals={'d': d})
0.11647015693597496
>>> timeit.timeit('"t" in d', globals={'d': d})
0.0370339349610731
```

116 - 37 is 79 milliseconds, as predicted.