# read data from file with python

Tags: python

can't read all data from file useing Python

inside test.txt there is :

```
{'God': {u'user1@localhost': {}, u'user2@localhost': {}, u'user3@localhost': {}}}
```

and the code is :

```
# coding: utf-8

def read_file(filename):
    data=None
    try:
        fp = file(filename)
        data = fp.read()
        fp.close()
    except: pass
    return data

def read():
    file = 'test.txt'
    db = eval(read_file(file))
    if "God" in db:
        for x in db["God"]:
            data = x
            #print(x) $$ it'll print all data True but I do not need it, I will put instructions inside and I do not need to be repeated.
        print(x) # $$ print just 1 data from file

try: read()
except: pass
```

how can I let it to read all data from file

thx.

Comment: As general advice, never eval what you read in from file. Big security risk. Store/convert your data to a more appropriate form if necessary, but never eval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read File using `with` and `open` method.
2. `eval` file content to get content into dictionary format.
3. Use `has_key` to check `God key` is present or not. [use `in` ['has_key()' or 'in'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323410/has-key-or-in])
4. Use 'keys()`method to get all keys of` God value` dictionary.
5. use 'join()` string method

code:

```
def readFile(filepath):
    with open(filepath, "rb") as fp:
        data = fp.read()         
    db = eval(data)
    if "God" in db:
        godkeys= db["God"].keys()
        print "godkeys:-", godkeys
        print "Data:", ','.join(godkeys)

filepath = '/home/infogrid/Desktop/input1.txt'
readFile(filepath)
```

output:

```
$ python  workspace/vtestproject/study/test.py
godkeys:- [u'user3@localhost', u'user2@localhost', u'user1@localhost']
Data: user3@localhost,user2@localhost,user1@localhost
```

Comment: hi, much time taken for to do ctrl+k

Comment: `has_key` has been deprecated for years - preferred form is `if "God" in db:`

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: ok. but can you give more information on it.

Comment: @VivekSable - see details in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323410/has-key-or-in

Comment: @mr.somebody: Working, then upvote/accept answer :), just kidding :)

Answer (score 2):

To read all data from a text file just use [read](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) method of a file object, e.g.

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using file() try open()
in fact you should get in the habit of that. 
Developers are directed to use open() instead of file() in all cases.

Comment: same thing

file() or open()

print just 1 data

Answer (score -1):

```
db = eval(read_file(file))
```

db is a dictionary. Dictionary is collection of many pairs of key and value. To check if some key is in dict, we should use keys() function as below:

```
if "God" in db.keys():
```

Also, to get all data in dict, we just use items() to get pair of key and value.

```
for key, value in db["God"].items():
    print "Key", key
    print "Value", value
```

Comment: In line with other commenters' cautions about using `eval`, safer to use `ast.literal_eval`, which does not have the same risks of accidental or malicious command injection.

Comment: `if "God" in db:` is sufficient to check for a matching key, without incurring the overhead of building the list of keys by calling `keys()`.

Comment: we can use `if db.has_key("God")` instead

Comment: Unless you are targeting Python 2.2 or older, please don't use the deprecated method `has_key`, see comments on VivekSable's answer.