# Get the name of the dictionary that contains the given key in python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
a = {'name1':'tom'}
b = {'name2':'harry'}
c = {'name3':'peter'}
```

For a given key, I would like to get the name of the dictionary contains it.
Example:
If i give 'name2', I would like to get b as the result

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? For instance there's nothing preventing you from making a dict of dicts?

Comment: Would you like to get `b` as variable or `"b"` as string?

Comment: Why do you need the name of a variable (or reference to the variable)?

Comment: What happens if a key is in more than one dictionary?

Comment: In my work, they are actually huge dicts and hence I didnt combine them for better handling. I like to get b as a variable. The key will not be in more than one dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) to return the next value in a sequence, and filter it based on some criteria:

```
key = 'name2'
found = next(d for d in (a, b, c)
             if key in d)
```

Comment: This answer has been enlightenment for me... That said,  `next` supports a  default result via an optional argument,  that imo in this case can be used  fruitfully: `found = next((d for d in (a, b, c) if key in d),None)` followed by a conditional block `if found: ...`

Comment: The OP doesn't say what they want to do if the key doesn't exist. It's often [easier to ask forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {'name1':'tom'}
b = {'name2':'harry'}
c = {'name3':'peter'}

name = 'name2'

for k, v in locals().copy().items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        if name in v:
            print('"{}" contains id dict "{}"'.format(name, k))
# "name2" contains in dict "b"
```

But usually you shouldn't do it. Create dict of dicts and iterate through it:

```
ds = {
    'a': {'name1':'tom'},
    'b': {'name2':'harry'},
    'c': {'name3':'peter'},
}

name = 'name2'

for k, v in ds.items():
    if name in v:
        print('"{}" contains id dict "{}"'.format(name, k))
# "name2" contains in dict "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you would like to get `b` back as a *variable*, one way I can think of doing this is making a list of your dictionaries and enumerating through them.

```
a = {'name1':'tom'}
b = {'name2':'harry'}
c = {'name3':'peter'}
name = 'name2'

dicts = list(a,b,c)
required_dic = findDict(dicts)


def findDict(dicts):    
    for obj in dicts:
        if "name2" in obj:
            return obj
```

but as @germn said, a better idea would be to create a nested dictionary.

Comment: `dict.has_key(key)` [is deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key) in favour of `key in dict`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323410/has-key-or-in)

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks! I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you put references to your dictionaries in an iterable

```
l = [da, db, dc, ...]
```

that you initialize the reference to one of your dictionaries to an invalid value

```
d = None
```

to find which dictionary has `word` as a key it's simply

```
for _ in l:
    if word in _:
        d = _
        break
```

at this point, either you didn't find `word` in any of your dicts and `d` is hence still equal to `None`, or you've found the dictionary containing `word`
and you can do everything you want to it

```
if d:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a mapping dict, which maps the key to variable binding:

`{"name1" : a, "name2" : b, "name3" : c}`

Comment: They contain a huge number of nested keys, so mapping is not possible for all the keys I guess