# Key exists in nullable dict in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python dictionary object that will get value by a user. Also the user may leave it as `None`.

I want to check if my dict has a specific key or not, I tried `if key in dict` but I got `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` error when my dict is `None`.

I need one line statement that returns `False` either my dict is `None` or my dict does not have that key. 
Here is my code: (form is the dictionary)

```
if 'key' not in form:
    # Do somethin
```

Comment: can you please show us your code? Also do not use names that Python already uses like `dict`. Name your dicts something else

Comment: simply check first before iteration if dict: print("True").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you must have a one-liner, but this is one:

```
False if d is None or k not in d else d[k]
```

Or (thanks @Chris_Rands for the hint)

```
False if not d else d.get(k, False)
```

If you simply want to test if the dict contains the key:

```
k in d if d else False
```

Comment: `False if d is None or d.get(k, False)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands - the `or` should be an `else`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: good suggestion, but `else` would be better than `or`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary togetether with `dict.get(key, default)`:

```
d = None
k = d.get("myKex", False) if d else False  # dicts that are None are "False"

d = {2 : "GotIt"}
k2 = d.get("2", False) if d else False     # get() allows a default if key not present
k3 = d.get(2, False) if d else False       # got it ...


print (k, k2, k3)
```

Output:

```
(False, False, 'GotIt')
```

Further reading:

- [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)
- [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

Answer (score 1):

One liner for checking not None and key presence. I assume `my_dict` has the values from user

```
result = (my_dict is not None) and (key in my_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the one line statement as follows:

```
True if dict and key in dict else False;
```

So then, returns False either dict is None or dict does not have that key.

Answer (score 0):

```
if dict is not None:
  if key in dict.keys():
    return True
return False
```

Comment: thanks for the replay. but i need one line statement.

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar you never *need* a one liner in Python

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if dict.has_key('specific-key-name-here'):
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323410/has-key-or-in?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa