# How to replace has_key in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I try to install [Auto-SelfControl](https://github.com/andreasgrill/auto-selfcontrol) and got stuck when executing this command:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python auto-selfcontrol.py
```

It shows the error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'

I'm searching for solutions and end up with replacing *has_key* for *in* operator but as I only know the basics of python, the code is quite complex for me.

There're 3 places where *has_key* have been used, can you help me change it so I can run with python3?

1.

```
def check_if_running(username):
""" checks if self-control is already running. """
defaults = get_selfcontrol_settings(username)
return defaults.has_key("BlockStartedDate") and not NSDate.distantFuture().isEqualToDate_(defaults["BlockStartedDate"])
```

2-4.

```
def check_config(config):
""" checks whether the config file is correct """
if not config.has_key("username"):
    exit_with_error("No username specified in config.")
if config["username"] not in get_osx_usernames():
    exit_with_error(
            "Username '{username}' unknown.\nPlease use your OSX username instead.\n" \
            "If you have trouble finding it, just enter the command 'whoami'\n" \
            "in your terminal.".format(
                    username=config["username"]))
if not config.has_key("selfcontrol-path"):
    exit_with_error("The setting 'selfcontrol-path' is required and must point to the location of SelfControl.")
if not os.path.exists(config["selfcontrol-path"]):
    exit_with_error(
            "The setting 'selfcontrol-path' does not point to the correct location of SelfControl. " \
            "Please make sure to use an absolute path and include the '.app' extension, " \
            "e.g. /Applications/SelfControl.app")
if not config.has_key("block-schedules"):
    exit_with_error("The setting 'block-schedules' is required.")
if len(config["block-schedules"]) == 0:
    exit_with_error("You need at least one schedule in 'block-schedules'.")
if config.get("host-blacklist", None) is None:
    print("WARNING:")
    msg = "It is not recommended to directly use SelfControl's blacklist. Please use the 'host-blacklist' " \
          "setting instead."
    print(msg)
    syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_WARNING, msg)
```

Comment: Use Python 2, or try to use `2to3`.

Comment: `has_key` is deprecated in Python 3. Why don't you use Python 2.7 instead?

Comment: @anh-nguyen replace each check with syntax [`key in dict`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323426/1248974), e.g. `return defaults.has_key("BlockStartedDate") and not ...` replace with `return "BlockStartedDate" in defaults and not ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use 'has_key()' or 'in' on Python dicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323410/should-i-use-has-key-or-in-on-python-dicts/1323426#1323426)

Comment: @Selcuk: Given Python 2's end of life is less than a year away (end of life is January 1, 2020), migrating (e.g. with `2to3`) now is probably a good idea.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Fair point, but it's not like Python 2.x will disappear next year, or suddenly stop interpreting that script in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the piecemeal solutions in the other answers will work, that approach is flawed simply because it's too easy to make a small mistake, miss a place that needs fixing, etc. The better solution is to just use [the `2to3` converter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html). You could fix all of your files in one fell swoop with:

```bash
$ 2to3 -f has_key -w auto-selfcontrol.py
```

That only runs [the `has_key` fixer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-has_key) which converts from `dict.has_key(key)` to `key in dict`. Sure you could make the fix yourself, but this is a case where simple programmatic fixers work just fine. You might just want to run it without `-f has_key` so it applies all the fixers at once, in case there are any other breaking changes that apply between Py2 and Py3.

`2to3` handles just about everything automatically, with the exception of Py2 `str` type changes (where it's a code logic decision on whether a given `str` literal should be `bytes` or `str` in Py3) and integer division (where `/` might need to change to `//`, based on whether the computation is logically floating point division or floor division). But for `has_key`, it's pretty reliable.

Answer (score 7):

A formal source for the solution is here: https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dicts.html

The TL;DR is this:

```
some_dict.has_key('some key')
```

Is now:

```
'some key' in some_dict
```

So, in your code:

```
return defaults.has_key("BlockStartedDate") and not NSDate.distantFuture().isEqualToDate_(defaults["BlockStartedDate"])
```

Becomes:

```
return "BlockStartedDate" in defaults and not NSDate.distantFuture().isEqualToDate_(defaults["BlockStartedDate"])
```

Similarly, lines like:

```
if not config.has_key("selfcontrol-path"):
    # do something
```

Become like:

```
if "selfcontrol-path" not in config:
    # do something
```

Note that you could also write `if not "selfcontrol-path" in config:` but the example given above is considered more Pythonic and should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in python3.7.

```
   tmp = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
   print(tmp.__contains__('a')) #True
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace as follows**

1.

```
def check_if_running(username):
""" checks if self-control is already running. """
defaults = get_selfcontrol_settings(username)
return "BlockStartedDate" in defaults and not NSDate.distantFuture().isEqualToDate_(defaults["BlockStartedDate"])
```

2-4.

```
def check_config(config):
""" checks whether the config file is correct """
if not "username" in config:
    exit_with_error("No username specified in config.")
if config["username"] not in get_osx_usernames():
    exit_with_error(
            "Username '{username}' unknown.\nPlease use your OSX username instead.\n" \
            "If you have trouble finding it, just enter the command 'whoami'\n" \
            "in your terminal.".format(
                    username=config["username"]))
if not "selfcontrol-path" in config:
    exit_with_error("The setting 'selfcontrol-path' is required and must point to the location of SelfControl.")
if not os.path.exists(config["selfcontrol-path"]):
    exit_with_error(
            "The setting 'selfcontrol-path' does not point to the correct location of SelfControl. " \
            "Please make sure to use an absolute path and include the '.app' extension, " \
            "e.g. /Applications/SelfControl.app")
if not "block-schedules" in config:
    exit_with_error("The setting 'block-schedules' is required.")
if len(config["block-schedules"]) == 0:
    exit_with_error("You need at least one schedule in 'block-schedules'.")
if config.get("host-blacklist", None) is None:
    print("WARNING:")
    msg = "It is not recommended to directly use SelfControl's blacklist. Please use the 'host-blacklist' " \
          "setting instead."
    print(msg)
    syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_WARNING, msg)
```