# Python compatibility issue while running Apache Phoenix command

Tags: python, hbase, apache-phoenix

I Installed Hadoop , Pig, Hive, HBase and Zookeeper successfully.
I installed Apache Phoenix to access HBase. Below are my PATH variables.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
export PATH="/home/vijee/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

export HADOOP_HOME=/home/vijee/hadoop-2.7.7
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH="$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin"
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"

export ZOOKEEPER_HOME=/home/vijee/apache-zookeeper-3.6.2-bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin

export HBASE_HOME=/home/vijee/hbase-1.4.13-bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HBASE_HOME/bin

export PHOENIX_HOME=/home/vijee/apache-phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.4-bin
export PATH=$PATH:$PHOENIX_HOME/bin
```

I copied phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.4-client.jar, phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.4-server.jar, phoenix-core-4.15.0-HBase-1.4.jar to HBase lib directory and restarted Hbase and Zookeeper.
When I run the below Phoenix command, it is throwing error

```
(base) vijee@vijee-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S510p:~/apache-phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.4-bin/bin$ psql.py localhost $PHOENIX_HOME/examples/WEB_STAT.sql $PHOENIX_HOME/examples/WEB_STAT.csv $PHOENIX_HOME/examples/WEB_STAT_QUERIES.sql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vijee/apache-phoenix-4.15.0-HBase-1.4-bin/bin/psql.py", line 57, in <module>
    if hbase_env.has_key('JAVA_HOME'):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

My Python Version

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.3
```

I know it is Python compatability issue and psql.py is written for Python 2.x.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly searching, it looks like HBase-1.4 is from 2017, while the latest stable is 2.2.5 .. the release notes imply that it works with Python 3

Consider simply using the newer jar [Apache Archive Link for stable files](https://archive.apache.org/dist/hbase/stable/)

At least `psql.py` in the latest Apache Phoenix code does appear to support Python 3 https://github.com/apache/phoenix/blob/master/bin/psql.py so you should be able to get a newer version than you have which will work with it.

This can be seen in the latest commit to it

- commit history by-file on GitHub: https://github.com/apache/phoenix/commits/master/bin/psql.py
- [commit for Python3 support with `in` being fixed](https://github.com/apache/phoenix/commit/d3330faa600b58314ec3e1a3e022dfdd2d2d99b6#diff-944d94ca75cefd0d904608e48b98633b2ad3afbae68d14b8ef3d206d9c2b4c03R92)

---

If you must use 1.4.x, you may be able to run `psql.py` with Python 2 instead. Most operating systems will accept having them installed in parallel, though it may make some dependency management confusing and it is not a maintainable solution.

Comment: I installed hbase-2.2.6 and apache-phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0 and again throwing the same error. The psql.py is from apache-phoenix/bin directory. The python code inside psql.py and phoenix_utils.py are in Python 2.x format. where as my Python version is 3.8. I am new for HBase and there is no much information in the web about this issue.

Comment: @Green can you simply use Python 2?

Comment: I have Python 3.x and my PySpark is running on Python 3.x. I dont know how to use Python 2 only to run Phoenix.

Comment: If you install python2 (directions will depend on OS .. for Debian derivatives [`apt install python2.7`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981118/correct-way-to-install-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-17-10)) then you can run with it as `python2 psql.py <arguments>`. However, there is a lot of effort and the latest version should work with Python 3, so suspecting this I went and checked. The latest version _does_ support it, so I'd encourage you to use that, as it will be much more maintainable (Python 2 support ended at the start of this year and the project is clearly now being developed with Python 3)

Comment: @Green I've edited my answer to include that information, along with a few supporting links!

Comment: Wonderful I succeded thanks...... I made required changes in python script files in Phoenix bin folder as in Git.

Answer (score 0):

`.has_key` was removed in 3.x, use `in` instead!

See also [Should I use 'has_key()' or 'in' on Python dicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323426/4541045)