# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable in Python3 OR Python2, resulting in a memory error

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

sorry if this is a repeat question, but I've had a look at the other answers, and they didn't help me solve the issue I had here.

I'm calling a python script in the command line: `plink2treemix.py` using:

```
python3 plink2treemix.py ~/directory/data.vcf.frq.strat.gz ~/directory/chr22treemix
```

Below is the script (it's long, but there are two separate areas in the script that are potentially causing trouble):

```
import sys, os, gzip

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("plink2treemix.py [gzipped input file] [gzipped output file]")
    print("ERROR: improper command line")
    exit(1)
infile = gzip.open(sys.argv[1])
outfile = gzip.open(sys.argv[2], "w")


pop2rs = dict() #POTENTIALLY A PROBLEM?
rss = list()
rss2 = set()

line = infile.readline()
line = infile.readline()
while line:
    line = line.strip().split()
    rs = line[1]
    pop = line[2]
    mc = line[6]
    total = line[7]
    if rs not in rss2: 
        rss.append(rs)
    rss2.add(rs)
    if pop2rs.has_key(pop)==0:
        pop2rs[pop] =  dict()
    if pop2rs[pop].has_key(rs)==0: #ERROR OCCURRING HERE
        pop2rs[pop][rs] = " ".join([mc, total])
    line = infile.readline()

pops = pop2rs.keys()
for pop in pops:
    print >> outfile, pop,
print >> outfile, ""

for rs in rss:
    for pop in pops:
        tmp = pop2rs[pop][rs].split()
        c1 = int(tmp[0])
        c2 = int(tmp[1])
        c3 = c2-c1
        print >> outfile, ",".join([str(c1), str(c3)]),
    print >> outfile, ""
```

I get the error:

```
plink2treemix.py", line 28, in <module>
    if pop2rs.has_key(pop)==0:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

I've tried running this using Python2, but this uses so much memory that my terminal kills the process, and I get a TypeError too, (object 'dict() not callable).

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Python3 don't have `has_key`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323410/should-i-use-has-key-or-in-on-python-dicts)

Comment: `dict()` is perfectly well callable. It's essentially the programmatic way to create an empty dict, equivalent to `{}`. However, `dict` does not _and never has had_ a `.has_key()` function. You can check whether a dict contains a given key by doing `if key in dict`, or check if it's absent by doing `if key not in dict`. That aside, your syntax `print >> outfile` looks more like a C-like language than like python. Are you sure you're trying to code python?

Comment: As an aside, don't use the whole `line = f.readline()` and `while line: ...` to iterate over a file line-by-line, use a *for loop*, all you need is `for line in f: ...`

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I think so I'm meant to be using python here? But I based this script off one I got to use a different programme  (treemix) for phylogenetic trees - so I think it should work (if I can get it past the dict() error that is). Where should I put the changes for the code? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Green *cough*"never has had"*cough*https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key — Also: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry to be dumb - but how/where would that fit into my script?

Comment: TL;DR: this code was written for Python 2. It may or may not be possible to port it to Python 3 relatively easily; that's too big a question for us to answer.

Comment: @deceze you have a great point. I shifted the line 28 to ```if pop2rs in (pop)==0:``` , and I got  ```TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'```. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Remplace `if pop2rs.has_key(pop)==0:` with `if pop not in pop2rs:`. It will return a boolean value of True if the key is not in the dictionary and the code in the if block would therefore execute.

Comment: @SamirAhmane Thank you! This worked - but now I'm getting a different error: ```<gzip _io.BufferedWriter name='/home/usr/data.treemix.frq.gz' 0x7f6844c6b290> ``` , which essentially returns an empty and corrupted frame.